# Camera / raspistill - output image is black although preview worked

Tags: camera

I just installed the v2 NoIR camera module in a Pi 3. I try `raspistill -o test.jpg -t 5000`. I see proper preview for 5 seconds, then preview window closes and I find the file `test.jpg`, but despite the preview having been ok that picture is just black. What I do wrong?

Comment: Could you try flipping the order of -o test.jpg and -t 5000?

Comment: @goobering Thanks, flipping the args seem to do the trick. Please add as an answer.

Comment: Err ... the order of the options to raspistill has no effect at all; options are [parsed up front](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiStill.c#L1772) then the resulting values (like timeout etc.) are used in the same way regardless of the order they were specified in. Whatever fixed your issue I can pretty much guarantee it wasn't the ordering of the options.

Comment: @DaveJones Well I can only tell what I see. But what I also see is that if I shoot multiple images with timelapse the early ones can go completely bananas with respect to exposure, even if using the same awb, shutter times etc. So definitely this tool `raspistill` has some severe bugs built it. Another thing that guarantees black images is the `--ISO` setting, no matter what value you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the options passed to raspistill is non-trivial - you should always finish with your output file location, not with an option.

In this case, swapping the preview timer option with the output location worked:

**Original/non-working:**

```
raspistill -o test.jpg -t 5000
```

**Amended/working:**

```
raspistill -t 5000 -o test.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem of the preview mode. If I choose `--nopreview`, image comes out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Jhony come lately

i do this:
raspistill -t 5000 -awb off -ex off -drc off -ss 5400 -awbg 1.1,1.95 -ISO 120 -ag 1 -dg 1 -vf -hf -o LastImageName.jpg

and get a good preview and a black file.

when i remove the "-ex off" i get an over exposed image.
any ideas?